# StopCoroutine not working not even StartCoroutine(string), StopCoroutine(string) in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I can't understand why.

I already read lots of documents about it and there are lots of comments that

StopCoroutine(string) can only stop the coroutine starts with StartCoroutine(string)

the code is below.

In Class CharTouchControl.cpp

```
if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Q ) )
{
    _CharControl.StartCoroutine("useFever", 10);
}
```

_CharControl is a member of CharTouchControl and of course _CharControl is referencing the CharControl instance below.

And InClass CharControl

```
public IEnumerator useFever(float _duration = 10)
{
    if( m_nUseFever < _nFeverMax )
    {
        Debug.Log("Stop!!");
        StopCoroutine("useFever");
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    m_fgCharState = CharState._FEVER;

    // fever particle
    m_psFeverPaticle.Simulate(4);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
} // end of useFever
```

When m_nUseFever < _nFeverMax is true, i can see "Stop!!" log,

but the coroutine don't stop and simulate paticles.

anybody help for this?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why are you using `StopCoroutine` from inside the coroutine? Use `yield break` in first `if` statement instead.

Comment: You call `StopCoroutine`, which prevents the rest of the function (which includes the particle simulation) from executing. What is is that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Jerdak mentioned, you should use yield break when your inside the Coroutine. 
the coroutine will automatically stop when it finishes its code block. Using yield break, should send it to the end of the code block.

Additionally you could modify your code so that it only runs the code block if the condition is true. Ive done this in the example below. If the condition is false the coroutine will just wait for the end of the frame and then exit.

```
public IEnumerator useFever()
{
    if( m_nUseFever > _nFeverMax )
    {
        m_fgCharState = CharState._FEVER;

        // fever particle
        m_psFeverPaticle.Simulate(4);
    }

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();        
} //Coroutine automatically exits here
```

EDIT:
Dan Puzey brought up a good point, Are you sure shouldn't be using

`Invoke("useFever",10)` or `InvokeRepeating ("useFever",10,1)`

instead? From your code it looks like you just want to run the useFever function in 10 seconds. If thats the case, you should be invoking it instead of running it as a coroutine, and useFever should be a normal function.

Just for reference, there is also `CancelInvoke("useFever")`

Comment: If that code works as the OP intends, there's no value running it in a coroutine - it'll run to completion in a single frame anyway. Also, there's rarely value in the final line of a coroutine being a `yield` (unless you're chaining coroutines).

Comment: I agree with you but he had placed it in there, so when I was refactoring his code, I figured he had his reasons. I figured it was for "timing" reasons. Its not up for me to decide